# Calculation Error in Crystal Report Fomula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have 2 decimal fields: GrossSalary and Deductions. In the report, I created a formula field named NetSalary, which is:

```
If Not IsNull({SalaryDetails.GrossAmount}) Then
 {SalaryDetails.GrossAmount} - {SalaryDetails.Deduction}
```

When data is available the report runs correctly, but if not I get the following error

```
A number, currency amount,date,time, or date-time is required here.
Details:errorKind
Error in File tempxxxxxxxxx.rpt:
Error in formula NetAmount:
'If Not IsNull({SalaryDetails.GrossAmount}) Then
'
A number,currency amount,date,time, or date-time is required here.
Details:errorKind
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are the values NULL or are they empty strings?  If Not IsNull({SalaryDetails.GrossAmount}) AND {SalaryDetails.GrossAmount} <> ""  Then ... I would also check your database to make sure there aren't any alpha characters because that will also cause that message.

Comment: i also included empty check. But if i use directly i got error. So i used like  If Not IsNull({SalaryDetails.GrossAmount}) AND CSTR({SalaryDetails.GrossAmount}) <> "" Then.. But same issue

Comment: Can you try using CDBL() around your decimal fields? Are you sure there's no alpha chars in the database?

Comment: @Andrew is correct, Crystal thinks that either {SalaryDetails.GrossAmount} or {SalaryDetails.Deduction} is not a number.  That can happen if the field is a string field of some type (like VARCHAR), even if it contains only numbers.  Try the CDBL() trick for one field and check for the error, then try the other one. (And if you still get the error, try both fields.)

Comment: Thanks friend. I added CDBL in both field and it is success now. Kindly tell me what is this alpha characters. Actually the report source is LINQ query and the problem raised when no data for the input parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Reports will throw this error if it believes it is working with a value that is not a number.  Crystal has many conversion functions like (CDBL, CSTR, etc) and also data check functions (IsNull, IsNumeric, etc) that you can use.

In your particular case, converting the values to a DBL (CDBL({field}) solves your problem after Crystal checks for null values or blanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CDBL or IsNumeric function is fine working e.g :

{@Total} / 100 * CDBL({tblinvdetail.disc}). In this formula, disc is the discount column of tblinvdetail table. We assume that disc column also accept null values. To Avoide this error the CDBL or IsNumeric function convert null to 0 value. You should precautionally apply cdbl or IsNumeric fucntion always in any formula in Crystal Report to avoid this  kind of error. Use IsNumeric Function if there the value of output has no floating points other wise CDBL function. You can also use IsNull Function to determine null value e.g:

if IsNull({tblinvdetail.disc}) then
  "0"
else
  {@Total} / 100 * {tblinvdetail.disc}

=====================================================================
Munawar Shah AFridi
(MCSD.net)