# i get error in formula fields in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i want if x is greater than y then display the x else display nothing. here's my code

```
    numberVar x := sum({LedgerTbl.Debitables}) ;
    numberVar y := sum({LedgerTbl.Creditables});
    StringVar message := " ";
    if x > y then
    x
    else
    message
```

but what i did always gives me an error "A Number is required here". anyone can help me out thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to use variables to solve this problem.

Instead, try:

```
// returns a numeric value or a Null
if sum({LedgerTbl.Debitables}) > sum({LedgerTbl.Creditables}) then
  sum({LedgerTbl.Debitables})
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Check your data field type in the db it must be INT.
2- Try ToNumber function as follow :

```
 numberVar x := (sum(ToNumber({LedgerTbl.Debitables})));
```

[Calculation Error in Crystal Report Fomula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747204/calculation-error-in-crystal-report-fomula)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use one `number value` and one `string value` hence the error.

USe totext to convert number to string and use as below.

```
numberVar x := sum({LedgerTbl.Debitables}) ;
    numberVar y := sum({LedgerTbl.Creditables});
    StringVar message := " ";
    if x > y then
    ToText(x)
    else
    message
```